# svn refuses to add directory in its database, causing "out of date" on files check in

Tags: svn, addition

We had a problem with svn (disk full), before managing to increase the volume size I did
"svn delete" to a directory, mistakenly thinking it'll reduce some used disk space.

Now the disk space is sufficient again but I can't "svn add" subdirectories below the directory
which I did "svn delete" and later "svn add" (except one subdirectory, I can't understand
what's different with it compared to others).

When doing "svn ls ", only one subdirectory is shown instead of many.
On the client directories, I did "svn revert  followed by "svn update "
followed by "svn ci " followed by "svn ci ".
There were no errors during these commands but if I attempt to change a file
and "svn ci " I get " out of date" error and if I do
"svn ls " I don't see the directory of the file
listed there, which is probably the reason for "out of date" error.

But why hasn't been the directory added to the server database tree, desipe "svn ci" not producing
any errors?

TIA!

```
.../include>svn ci -m "" xilinx_ip_lib/e1_prbs_ila/e1_prbs_ila.xci
.../include>cp ~/temp/e1_prbs_ila.xci xilinx_ip_lib/e1_prbs_ila/e1_prbs_ila.xci
cp: overwrite xilinx_ip_lib/e1_prbs_ila/e1_prbs_ila.xci? y
.../include>svn status xilinx_ip_lib/e1_prbs_ila
M       xilinx_ip_lib/e1_prbs_ila/e1_prbs_ila.xci
.../include>svn ci -m "" xilinx_ip_lib/e1_prbs_ila/e1_prbs_ila.xci
Sending        xilinx_ip_lib/e1_prbs_ila/e1_prbs_ila.xci
svn: E155011: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E155011: File '<client path>/include/xilinx_ip_lib/e1_prbs_ila/e1_prbs_ila.xci' is out of date
svn: E160013: File not found: transaction '25693-1', path '<client path>/include/xilinx_ip_lib/e1_prbs_ila/e1_prbs_ila.xci'
.../include>svn ls <server URL+path>/include/xilinx_ip_lib/e1_prbs_ila
svn: warning: W160013: URL '<server URL+path>/include/xilinx_ip_lib/e1_prbs_ila' non-existent in revision 25693
svn: E200009: Could not list all targets because some targets don't exist
```

The directory which I tried to "svn delete" and later "svn add" is "/include/xilinx_ip_lib".

Comment: You need to `svn update` your working copy. If this doesn’t help, you can simply check out a new working copy. And BTW make sure that your existing one doesn’t have uncommitted changes which you don’t want to lose.